# unexpected termination

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs fine locally. After deploying it to SQL Server, I get an unexpected error. Under data flow task, "validation has started" is the last message I see.

To fix the problem I set "delay validation" to `True` everywhere. Then, I get:

> Data flow task 1;Error : SSIS Error code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR . An OLE DB
>   Error has occurred .Error code 0x80004005.An Ole db record is
>   available ,Source "Microsoft Access database Engine" Hresult 0x0004005
>   Description "unexpected error from external database driver (1)"

Comment: I assume you have Office installed on your workstation.Does the server where SSIS package is deployed have the Microsoft Access Database Engine installed?

Comment: Yes, I have installed access driver 10 and i have .xlsx file . The security patch KB4041693 will cause this issue.